# Why can't Banshee Remote connect to server?

Tags: applications, samsung-galaxy-s-3, remote-control

I'm trying to use [Banshee Remote](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.nstamato.bansheeremote&hl=en) with my Samsung Galaxy S3, but everytime I try to add a new server, it says `Can't connect to server. Check your settings`. There are only two settings:

1. IP Adress, which I got from [whatismyip.org](http://whatismyip.org)
2. Port, which I got from Banshee (Edit->Preferences->Remote Control->Banshee remote port

Is there anything I can try to do to fix this?

Notes:
I am using Banshee 2.4.1 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: Are you connected to the same WiFi network? You need the internal IP, not the external.

Comment: That was it. You should add this as an answer so I can select it as correct. I suppose if I were to use 3G on my phone, then I would need the external ip, right?

Comment: Yup. You would also need to some port forwarding ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure your phone is connected to the same WiFi network as your computer, and remember to use the internal IP.

To do this through 3G you would need to forward ports and use your external IP.